# Any possibilities for hasClass Name make true all the child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
If(element.toElement.className == 'section')
```

if the class name matches with the section  but I want when the user clicks any child elements of section div I want to make true for the condition.

When user click any div I need to check the class name if class name is match I need to execute the function.

But issue is when user click child element of matched class is going to else condition.

Any possibilities over there?

Comment: `$(this).find(".classname")`?

Comment: `if` is wrong (maybe typo).. use `==` or `===`

Comment: add click event to parent , it will work for all child element

Comment: Please try to describe more what you're trying to achieve here.. if there's any events try to add the relevant code...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki : when user click any div i need to check the class name if class name is match i need to execute the function.

But issue is when user click child element of matched class is going to else condition.

Comment: Please post the click event and example of HTML structure you've..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).parents().hasClass('section');
```

Comment: Do try to add some explanation to your answers.